# Error Message: this.stopPropagation is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

can someone explain to me why I get this error message when I use the **stopPropagation** method? I have a simple event where if you click on a **div** with the id of **ex1**, a function will run which will cause the background color of the div to be deep pink. I then added the stopPropagation method to stop the function. But, I get an error message in the console that it is not function, however, the stopPropagation method still works.

HTML

```
<div id="ex1"><h2>Example 1</h2><p></p><h4>results:</h4></div>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('ex1').addEventListener('click', function(e){
this.stopPropagation();
this.style.backgroundColor = 'deeppink';
},false);
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `this`, `this` is referring to the element clicked. Use `e`, which is the event object.

[Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```js
document.getElementById('ex1').addEventListener('click', function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
this.style.backgroundColor = 'deeppink';
},false);
```

```html
<div id="ex1"><h2>Example 1</h2><p></p><h4>results:</h4></div>
```